# Python 3 class and subclass: Creating triangles and squares

Tags: python-3.x, class, subclass

I am teaching myself about Python class and subclass. I am trying to do a question in the book but I got stuck. I am trying to create 3 triangles and 4 squares and print out all the attributes of one the triangles and one of the squares but I am not sure how. Thank you for your help! . The book gave me this:

```
> class Shape(object):
>       def __init__(self, corner=10):
>        self.__corner= corner
>        self.__sides=corner
```

Here is what I have so far:

> ```
> class Shape(object):
>       def __init__(self, corner=10):
>        self.__corner= corner
>        self.__sides=corner
>
>   def set_corner(self, corner):
>     self.__corner= corner
>   def set_sides(self, corner):
>     self.__sides= corner
>   def get_corner(self):
>     return self.__corner
>   def get_sides(self):
>     return self.__sides
>
> class Square(Shape):
>   def __init__(self, corner, area):
>     Shape.__init__(self, corner=10)
>     self.__area=area
>   def set_area(self,area):
>     self.__area= area
>   def get_area(self,area):
>     return self.__area
>
> class Triangle(Shape):
>   def __init__(self, corner, height):
>     Shape.__init__(self, corner=10)
>     self.__height=height
>   def set_height(self,height):
>     self.__height= height
>   def get_height(self,height):
>     return self.__height
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Using your code (with minimal modification) here's one way to do it:

```
class Square(Shape):
    def __init__(self, corner, area):
        Shape.__init__(self, corner = 10)
        self.__area = area
    def set_area(self):
        self.__area = area
    def get_area(self):
        return self.__area

class Triangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, corner, height):
        Shape.__init__(self, corner = 10)
        self.__height = height
    def set_height(self):
        self.__height = height
    def get_height(self):
        return self.__height

# example triangle
t1 = Triangle(3, 50)

# example square
s1 = Square(5, 20)

# print the attributes
print('Triangle 1 height: {height} units.'.format(height=t1.get_height()))
print('Square 1 area: {area} sq. units.'.format(area=s1.get_area()))
```

prints:

```
Triangle 1 height: 50 units.
Square 1 area: 20 sq. units.
```

May need to adjust the values for reasonable results.